# Text/Shape Inner Beveling effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Any idea of how to create this effect solely with CSS3
[image]

I cant seem to get close to creating this "Inner Beveling" Effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1**

This won't produce a bevelled 3D effect, but it *is* relatively straightforward to style the text so that it appears to stand out from the page, 3-dimensionally:

```css
h1 {
font-size: 60px;
color: rgb(254,127,0);
text-shadow:
1px 1px rgb(204,93,0),
2px 2px rgb(204,93,0),
3px 3px rgb(204,93,0),
4px 4px rgb(204,93,0),
5px 5px rgb(204,93,0),
6px 6px rgb(204,93,0);
}
```

```html
<h1>Test Text</h1>
```

## =====

**Approach 2**

You can also deploy CSS `text-shadow` in a more complex manner, to try to recreate a bevel effect. In this example, the x looks quite good, but none of the other letters compare.

```css
h1 {
font-size: 60px;
font-weight: lighter;
font-stretch: ultra-condensed;
letter-spacing:20px;
color: rgb(255,127,0);
text-shadow:
1px 0px rgb(204,93,0),
-1px 0px rgb(255,186,127),
2px 0px rgb(204,93,0),
-2px 0px rgb(255,186,127),
3px 0px rgb(204,93,0),
-3px 0px rgb(255,186,127),
4px 0px rgb(204,93,0),
-4px 0px rgb(255,186,127),
5px 0px rgb(204,93,0),
-5px 0px rgb(255,186,127);
}
```

```html
<h1>Test Text</h1>
```

## =====

**Approach 3**

A much more sophisticated (albeit more experimental) approach is to use SVG filters - which are now supported by all major contemporary browsers.

The example below doesn't look a lot like your original conception, but SVG filters are so versatile that - given enough practice and knowhow (and access to the appropriate `@font-face`) - you could duplicate it exactly.

**N.B.** *A useful introduction to what SVG Filters are capable of is available in this May 2015 Article:*

[The Art Of The SVG Filter And Why It Is Awesome](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/why-the-svg-filter-is-awesome/) *by Dirk Weber*

```html
<svg>

<defs>

<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[
.beveled {
filter: url(#bevel-filter);
font-size: 60px;
font-weight:900;
}
]]>
</style>

<filter id="bevel-filter">

<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" in="SourceAlpha" result="BLUR"/>

<feSpecularLighting surfaceScale="6" specularConstant="1" specularExponent="30" lighting-color="#white" in="BLUR" result="SPECULAR">
<fePointLight x="40" y="-30" z="200" />
</feSpecularLighting>

<feComposite operator="in" in="SPECULAR" in2="SourceAlpha" result="COMPOSITE"/>

<feMerge>
<feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
<feMergeNode in="COMPOSITE"/>
</feMerge>

</filter>

</defs>

<g class="beveled">
<text x="10" y="60" fill="rgb(255,127,0)">Test Text</text>
</g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Yeah ive been playing with this type of styling, i really need the inner bevel effect however. Are yous saying this cant be done with css3?

Comment: I hunted around a bit to see what else I could find. Have a look at the examples above.

Comment: Approach 3 looks very promising @Rounin. I can see this going a long way.